# how to add embedded ruby in style tag

Tags: css, ruby, embedded-ruby

I want to define the width of a status bar dynamically.

First I define the variable:

```
<% target = (clicks/total_clicks)*100 %>
```

Then I try to embed the ruby code into a css width tag:

```
<div class="bar" style="width: <%= target %>%">
```

However, the html output looks like this

```
<div class="progress progress-striped">
<div class="bar" style="width: 0%"></div>
</div>
```

I tried to convert the target var as a string:

```
<% target = ((clicks/total_clicks)*100).to_s %>
```

I obviously also tried to assign a not-dynamic value as well:

```
<% target = 40.to_s %>
```

But with no success.

How can I embed a ruby var into a CSS style tag?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try: `<%=target = (clicks/total_clicks)*100 %>`

Comment: doens't work.
I tried `style="width: <%= target = 50 %>%"` which works fine.
But wenn trying `style="width: <%= target = (10/20)/100 %>%"` - gives me again a 0.

Comment: `<% target = ((clicks.to_f/total_clicks.to_f)*100.0).to_s %>` (note the use of `.to_f`)
`<div class="bar" style="width: '#{target}%'">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting 0 because of how you are using the numbers. You are using `Integers`. Do this:

`<%= target = (Float(10)/Float(20))/100 %>`

Using floats will allow you to get the percentage you are using. When you use Integers, it will generally round the number off. Hope this helps.

EDIT:

You can also use the `.to_f` method as well, instead of `Float`

Comment: Good. Glad I was able to help you.